# Explode by dashed in php

Tags: php, explode

hello everyone i am getting value like **Array ( [2] => FAB(CBY-DJ9)--9 )**, i want two separate value like this `FAB(CBY-DJ9)` and `9` by loop, kindly help me i am a beginner.

hello everyone i am getting value like **Array ( [2] => FAB(CBY-DJ9)--9 )**, i want two separate value like this `FAB(CBY-DJ9)` and `9` by loop, kindly help me i am a beginner.hello everyone i am getting value like **Array ( [2] => FAB(CBY-DJ9)--9 )**, i want two separate value like this `FAB(CBY-DJ9)` and `9` by loop, kindly help me i am a beginner

Answer (score -1):

With explode() you can seperate them.

```
$item = 'FAB(CBY-DJ9)--9';
list($code, $number) = explode('--', $item);
```

Comment: Please close basic duplicates (that have been asked many times) instead of answering.